Convert an integer to its corresponding finite field element and vice versa in Magma
I want to be able to convert an integer in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to its corresponding element in GF$(2^k)$ where $2^k = n$ and vice versa. In SageMath this can be done directly using the from_integer() and to_integer() methods in the base finite field class but I wasn't able to find any similar methods to do this directly in the Magma handbook. Any pointers on this would be much appreciated.

It seems like this is a very specific command in SageMath that only works in fields of characteristic 2? I don't think Magma has something that does this directly, but you could just convert the integer to a base 2 sequence of length k, and then coerce that into the field. I would probably write a custom function for this using IntegerToSequence.
